# How to get the content of text area in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the content I write (in view) in the textarea , in the controller.

Basically, I have a textarea and want to get it's text in controller how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try following the "Getting Started" tutorial for MVC?

Comment: Its handler actually , textarea handler

Answer (score 0):

The main way to post form's contents to an Action is to have HTML elements with their "name" attribute with the same value as asked by the action.

That's why when you use the default Html Helpers with a Typed View, they render elements with the models property names.
So, if your controller asks for: `public ActionResult GetClient(int clientId)`
it will receive the value if the form has an element like: `<textarea name="clientId"></textarea>` when you submit.